# Peltier not cooling properly (draws less current than usual)

Tags: peltier

I have two peltiers (12710) bought at same time,few months ago. It worked properly months ago. Now, when I apply same voltage across them (with both peltiers having similar heat sink
configuration), One of them gets less cooling (draws less current) compared to the other ex: one draws 4.3A "good cooling" and  other draws 1.6A "less cooling" , with same voltage "parallel" across them).

Is that a damage made by me, while using for long days?

Comment: Sounds like damage. No way to tell who or what caused the damage though.

Comment: How are you driving the Peltiers?

Comment: I use SMPS for driving peltiers Ernesto @Ernesto